# Core Data insert validation (validateForInsert) fires too early?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, validation, core-data

I'm trying to setup validation in core data to a simple managed object structure.

There is a `Building` and `Floor` and a one-to-many relationship between both (on Building has many Floors).

The validator in the `Floor` looks like this

```
// extension of auto generated managed object (Floor)
extension Floor {
    override public func validateForInsert() throws {
        try super.validateForInsert()
        if (self.building == nil) {
            throw ValidationError.missingBuilding("a floor requires a building")
        }
    }
}
```

And my simple manager for testing:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ObjectNodeManager {

    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!

    init(container: NSPersistentContainer) {
        self.persistentContainer = container
        self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }

    lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    }()

    func insertObjectNode(objectNode: ObjectNode) -> ObjectNode? {
        backgroundContext.insert(objectNode)
        return objectNode
    }

    func save() {
        if backgroundContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try backgroundContext.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("save error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to create an save a new building and floor I get an exception.

```
let building = Building(context: manager.backgroundContext)
let floor = Floor(context: manager.backgroundContext)
floor.building = building // VALIDATION EXCEPTION!

// a basic backgroundContext.save() (persistentContainer) in the manager
manager.save()
```

With the `validationForInsert` it is impossible for me to insert/save the managed objects. Alternatively I could use `validationForUpdate` but this would be too late, since I do not want to store a `Floor` without the proper relationship to the `Building`.

Any suggestion how to save manage object with required relationships and validation on insert?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling the validateForInsert()? Also, please upload your code for Floor(context:_) method.

Comment: I am not calling the `validateFroInsert`. It is automatically called in the `Floor` extension.
I added the `extension` part above to make clear that `Floor` is an extension of a managed object.

The `Floor(context:_)` method is a standard core data managed object initialiser.

Comment: It looks like you have synchronisation issue. The `validationForInsert` is called only upon saving the context. It looks like it is triggered before by somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by synchronisation issue. The implementation is very basic. I will add the manager for better understanding.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling the save somewhere else? This problem may occur if the save was called before the Floor object was assigned the building.

Comment: I see what you mean. I also checked the code. There is no save called before. Also my test is very short and simple and executes the manager.save() at the end, but the validation exception it thrown before (just after initialisation of the managed object model)

Answer (score 1):

When I first started using Core Data in 2009, I ran into similar *false alarm* problems.  My solution was and still is: **Do not use Core Data's validation in your top-level *main* managed object context**. That is, do not implement `validateForInsert()`.  Even if Core Data does properly flag a *true* alarm, as you have seen, it occurs during saving, which is too late to do anything intelligent about it.  Users are not happy when their work cannot be saved.

You may wish to use Core Data's validation in a *child* managed object context.  In this case, you are typically in a view controller, the validation error is caught immediately after the user entered it, and your immediate presentation of the error will make sense to the user.

Comment: When I read that Adam had solved the problem, my first reaction was to delete this non-answer of mine.  But upon reflection, I'm sticking with it.  If you avoid Core Data's validation, you avoid confusing validation errors which often occur when `awakeFromInsert/Fetch`, `tearDown`, `willTurnIntoFault`, etc. are invoked by multiple related objects in the same run loop cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The `manager.background` context always returns a new context, your `building` and `floor` exist in two different contexts.

```
let backgroundContext = manager.backgroundContext
let building = Building(context: backgroundContext)
let floor = Floor(context: backgroundContext)
floor.building = building
manager.save()
```

Comment: Actually both are in the same context since the code in my initial question will return the same context once it is initialized. I see both managed objects in the same context.

Even if I create only the `Floor` without the `Building` I will get the validation error before `manager.save()`. `validateForInsert` is immediately executed as soon as ANY managed object is instantiated.

Comment: Can you tell me the error which you are getting on trying to the save()?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a `save` error: `Fatal error: save error parentMissingError("parent missing for Building")`

The thing is, that it happens without running `manager.save()`.

Comment: I found it. The issue came from the `tearDown` of my `unit test` where everything is cleaned up and saved at the end. Thank you so much for digging with me. Sometimes you get code blind...Thanks again.

It is still confusing, since the test `tearDown` is executed after the test, but maybe with has some async behaviour I do not know about. At least I know where to look.